# How can I optimize GCC compilation for memory usage?

Tags: c, gcc

I am developing a library which should use as little memory as possible (I am not concerned about *anything* else, like the binary size, or speed optimizations).

Are there any GCC flags (or any other GCC-related options) I can use? Should I avoid some level of -O* optimization?

Comment: I actually don't know of any compiler options for _any_ compiler that control virtual memory usage.  That's controlled almost entirely by your code.  The only thing the compiler controls is binary size.

Comment: The compiler can only try to reduce the code size (with -Os). The amount of memory you use is entirely up to you--when you ask for a malloc(), do you want it say no?

Comment: If your architecture supports unaligned data fetching, you can prevent padding inside structs. `-fpack-struct` for gcc.

Comment: @holgac How can I check if my architecture supports unaligned data fetching?

Comment: You can probably find about your CPU on the internet. If not, take a look at your CPU's specifications. For example, x86 and x86_64 architectures support it, but it incurs a severe performance penalty. But unaligned memory access in SPARC or i64 would result in error.

Comment: What kind of library are you developing? How does it use memory? Please edit your question to improve it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You library -or any code in idiomatic C- has several kinds of memory usage :

- binary code size, and indeed `-Os` should optimize that
- heap memory, using [C dynamic allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), that is `malloc`; you obviously should know how, and how much, heap memory is allocated (and later `free`-d). The actual memory consumption would depend upon your particular `malloc` implementation (e.g. many implementations, when calling `malloc(25)` could in fact consume 32 bytes), not on the compiler. BTW, you might design your library to use some [memory pools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool) or even implement your own allocator (above OS syscalls like `mmap`, or above `malloc` etc...)
- local variables, that is the [call frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) on the call stack. This mostly depend upon your code (but an optimizing compiler, e.g. `-Os` or `-O2` for `gcc`, would probably use more registers and perhaps slightly less stack when optimizing). You could pass [-fstack-usage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) to `gcc` to ask it to give the size of every call frame and you might give [`-Wstack-usage=`*len*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.htm) to be warned when a call frame exceeds *len* bytes.
- global or static variables. You should know how much memory they need (and you might use `nm` or some other binutils program to query them). BTW, declaring *carefully* some variables inside a function as `static` would lower the stack consumption (but you cannot do that for every variable or every function).

Notice also that in *some limited* cases, GCC is doing [tail calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), and then the stack usage is lowered (since the stack frame of the caller is reused in the callee). (See also [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490324/how-do-i-check-if-gcc-is-performing-tail-recursion-optimization)).

You might also ask the compiler to pack some particular `struct`-s (beware, this could slowdown the performance significantly). You'll want to use some [type attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) like `__attribute__((packed))`, etc... and perhaps also some [variable attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) etc...

Perhaps you should read more about [Garbage Collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29), since GC techniques, concepts, and terminology might be relevant. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29816531/841108).

If on Linux, the [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) tool should be useful too... (and during the debugging phase the `-fsanitize=address` option of recent GCC).

You might perhaps also use some [code generation options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) like `-fstack-reuse=` or `-fshort-enums` or `-fpack-struct` or `-fstack-limit-symbol=` or `-fsplit-stack` ; *be very careful:* some such options make your binary code *incompatible* with your existing C (and others!) libraries (then you might need to recompile all used libraries, including your [`libc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), with the same code generation flags).

You probably should enable [link-time optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Time_Optimization) by [compiling *and linking* with `-flto`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) (in *addition* of other optimization flags like `-Os`).

You certainly should use a *recent version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)*. Notice that [GCC 5.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) has been released a few days ago (in april 2015).

If your library is large enough to worth the effort, you might even consider customizing your GCC compiler with [MELT](https://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) (to help you find out how to spend less memory). This might take weeks or months of work.

Answer (score 3):

there are advantages to using 'stack frames', but that does use more stack space to save the stack frame pointer.

You can tell the compiler to not use stack frames.  This will (generally) slightly increase the code size but will reduce the amount of stack used.

you can only use char and short for values rather than int.

It is poor programing practice, but can re-use variables and arrays for multiple purposes.

if some set of variables are mutually exclusive on usage, then can place them in a union.

If the function parameter lists are all very short, then can for the compiler to pass all the parameters in registers. (having an architecture with lots of general purpose registers really helps here.

Only use one malloc that contains ALL the area needed for malloc kind of operations, so as to minimize the amount of allocated memory overhead.

there are many techniques.  Most make the code much more difficult to debug/maintain and often make the code much harder for humans to read

Answer (score 1):

When possible, you can use -m32 option to compile your application for 32-bit. So, the application will consume only half of the memory on 64-bit systems.

```
apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
gcc -m32 application.c -o application
```